# R - "CAPdiscrim" and "lda" error "variable 1 appears to be constant within groups"

Tags: r, statistics, pca, vegan, linear-discriminant

so I've been trawling through existing questions for solutions to this one, but to no avail.

I have a dataset consisting of individuals (117), each with an observation from a different variable (12), and grouped by a factor variable with 8 levels.

I would like to do a canonical analysis of principal co-ordinates on these data based on the Anderson and Willis approach.  I started by using BiodiversityR::CAPdiscrim. Let's start with some example data:

```
individual <- c(1:30)
group <- rep(c("a","b","c"), 10)
Var1 <- rnorm(n = 30, mean = 3.0e-4,sd = 2.0e-6)
Var2 <- rnorm(n = 30, mean = 2.4e-4,sd = 2.0e-6)
Var3 <- rnorm(n = 30, mean = 7.0e-6,sd = 9.0e-9)
Var4 <- rnorm(n = 30, mean = 4.2e-5,sd = 1.0e-6)
Var5 <- rnorm(n = 30, mean = 1.0e-4,sd = 9.0e-6)
Var6 <- rnorm(n = 30, mean = 8.0e-5,sd = 1.0e-5)

df <- data.frame(cbind(individual, group, Var1, Var2, Var3, Var4, Var5, Var6))
df$Var1 <- as.numeric(levels(df$Var1))[as.integer(df$Var1)]
df$Var2 <- as.numeric(levels(df$Var2))[as.integer(df$Var2)]
df$Var3 <- as.numeric(levels(df$Var3))[as.integer(df$Var3)]
df$Var4 <- as.numeric(levels(df$Var4))[as.integer(df$Var4)]
df$Var5 <- as.numeric(levels(df$Var5))[as.integer(df$Var5)]
df$Var6 <- as.numeric(levels(df$Var6))[as.integer(df$Var6)]
```

CAPdiscrim requires data in a particular format:

```
vars <- df[3:8]
```

now we can run CAPdiscrim on the data

```
BiodiversityR::CAPdiscrim(vars~group,
                          data = df,
                          dist = "euclidean",
                          axes = 4,
                          m = 0,
                          permutations = 999)
```

Which returns:

> Error in lda.default(x, grouping, ...) : 
>    variable 1 appears to be constant within groups

We can use nearZeroVar to see if this is true (which is appears not to be true):

```
vars_check <- nearZeroVar(vars, saveMetrics = TRUE, names = TRUE)
vars_check

    freqRatio percentUnique zeroVar   nzv
Var1         1           100   FALSE FALSE
Var2         1           100   FALSE FALSE
Var3         1           100   FALSE FALSE
Var4         1           100   FALSE FALSE
Var5         1           100   FALSE FALSE
Var6         1           100   FALSE FALSE
```

Now I saw other questions regarding this error specific to lda() and I noticed that CAPdiscrim() calls vegdist(), cmdscale() and lda() so I tried to break down this analysis peice by peice:

```
dist_matrix <- vegdist(vars,
                       method = "euclidean",
                       binary = FALSE,
                       diag = FALSE,
                       upper = FALSE,
                       na.rm = TRUE)

PCA_vars <- cmdscale(d = dist_matrix,
                       k = 5,
                       eig = TRUE,
                       add = FALSE,
                       x.ret = FALSE)

LDA_pldist <- lda(x = PCA_vars$points,
                  grouping = df$group)
```

Which returns a very similar result:

> Error in lda.default(x, grouping, ...) : 
>    variables 1 2 3 4 5 appear to be constant within groups

Now in `lda()` there is an argument "tol" which can be used to remove this error when dealing with very small numbers, so I can do this:

```
LDA_pldist <- lda(x = PCA_vars$points,
                  grouping = df$group,
                  tol = 1.0e-25)
```

This provides some output, but doesn't include some of the features of `CAPdiscrim` such as allowing the function to determine the best number for "m" through permutations.

Can anyone suggest how to modify the tolerance in `CAPdiscrim()`? or how to carry out what `CAPdiscrim()` is doing under the hood manually with these other functions?

Any insight would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Author of BiodiversityR::CAPdiscrim has fixed the problem and this has been rolled out in subsequent package updates.  It was a case of some error-checks relying on absolute values making sense from an ecology perspective vs relative values compared to the input data.

Answer (score 0):

I was experiencing the exact same problem. After updating the package to `BiodiversityR_2.8-3`, the error went away.

(Using the data you provided)

```
BiodiversityR::CAPdiscrim(vars~group,
                          data = df,
                          dist = "euclidean",
                          axes = 4,
                          m = 0,
                          permutations = 999)
#Percentage of correct classifications was 26.66667 
#Significance of this percentage was 0.98999 

#Overall classification success (m=1) : 26.6666666666667 percent
#a (n=10) correct: 10 percent
#b (n=10) correct: 70 percent
#c (n=10) correct: 0 percent
#Warning message:
#In cmdscale(distmatrix, k = nrow(x) - 1, eig = T, add = add) :
# only 18 of the first 29 eigenvalues are > 0
```

Comment: Thanks for the update @J.Con.  I contacted the author and they provided me with a temporary fix whilst they were in the process of updating the package.  I'm happy to hear that the new update has fixed the problem as well.